# Android NDK: UnsatisfiedLinkError when using OpenAL shared library

Tags: android, android-ndk, openal

I am trying to use manually compiled OpenAL shared library in Android.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:=openal
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=../mylibs/libopenal.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES:=$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/AL
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In mylibs folder i have 3 files:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  21:12 libopenal.so -> libopenal.so.1
lrwxr-xr-x  21:12 libopenal.so.1 -> libopenal.so.1.13.0
-rwxr-xr-x  22:33 libopenal.so.1.13.0
```

Everything complies fine, but in runtime i get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13604): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:         link_image[1848]:  1296 could not load needed library 'libopenal.so.1' for 'libopenaltest.so'     (load_library[1120]: Library 'libopenal.so.1' not found)
E/AndroidRuntime(13604):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(13604):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime(13604):    at com.hz.openal.OpenActivity.<clinit>(OpenActivity.java:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(13604):    ... 15 more
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: The numeric version suffix on your .so files strongly suggests that these are not libraries which have been built for android, as the usual android build system does not do versioning that way.  Most likely you are trying to use libraries built for your development machine or some other non-android target, and that is just plain not going to work.  You can (to some degree) check the architecture of a library with the 'readelf' command.  Most likely you will end up having to rebuild the libraries with the ndk build system, or at least the android compiler (look into the stand alone toolchain)

Comment: And even if they were android-compatible objects, the sym link may not survive through the packaging and installation.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to rebuilt the library.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
LOCAL_MODULE := lib3rdparty-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib3rdparty.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += lib3rdparty-prebuilt
```

I think you are missing the last line  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES .....

and also you didn't loaded the "libopenal.so" library before loading the "libopenaltest.so" library. All the libraries need to be loaded using System.loadLibrary() before the dependent library is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, i checked LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES, it's ok. I've loaded "libopenal.so" (System.loadLibrary("openal");), but i get the same error.